# IE7 1 pixel above text

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/B53sh/5/
Here is my problem. Text in ie7 has 1px space  while at other browsers its 2px.It seems that problem exists at this font size.At larger font-size they are the same..
The designer wants it pixel perfect as there is an image to align there and this causes a little problem..

**UPDATE**
I think that when font-size is 12px doesnt work but when its 14px works. So i think that the only solution is conditional stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set on `li` `line-height: 15px` to see 1 pixel space from top or `line-height: 17px` to see 2 pixel space